# AngularJS passing json to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm still new in Angular but i'm doing some progress.. i think :)
I have problem passing json file from controller to directive using isolated scope.

This is my controller which talk to factory "dataArchive":

```
.controller('graphCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataArchive', function($scope, dataArchive){
    dataArchive.get().then(function(data){
        $scope.getData = data;
    });
}]);
```

Then i have directive which is using isolated scope.

```
.directive('dataGraph', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            getArchiveData: '='
        },
        template: '<div id="chartdiv"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs){
             var dati = scope.getArchiveData;
             console.log(dati);
        };
     };
 });
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="graphCtrl">
    <data-graph get-archive-data="getData"></data-graph>
</div>
```

In console i always get 'undefined'.

Where i am wrong and is this a good way?

Thanks you all.

Comment: Is the example code correct? You have getArchiveData in the scope definition, but you call scope.getWeatherData() in the the link function.

Comment: I was doing some testing, no no it's scope.getArchiveData. Anyway it's not correct, i get undefined instead of json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this code is async:

```
dataArchive.get().then(function(data){
        $scope.getData = data;
    });
```

The `link` function will run before the data is set on `getData`, and therefore the isolated scope variable will not be set at this time.  So, I believe you are seeing a timing issue.

To make sure that your directive binding is correct.  Try to set `$scope.getData` to a static value (e.g. `$scope.getData = [{ data: 'value'}]`).  This should work.

Also, Angular checks for changes (to rebind) based on object reference.  So, you might need to define `$scope.getData` in the controller (outside of the async call).  Then you might want to `push` all the data in (instead of replace the entire object with the assignment).

Hope this helps.